# Using Opencv and Hough Transform circle to detect circles (subscript error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, hough-transform, canny-operator

As right now is my school holiday, I decided to pick up some skills thus I'm attempting to learn how to use OpenCV features with visual studio c++ to detect how many cans is in the carton and had to group it 4 by 4.
[image]

I have tried various demo codes such as " opencv find:contour " , Template matching(doesn't work well as it cannot detect the rotation of the top lid)

The best method that I found out is that to combine Canny Edge Detection and Hough Transform Circle such that the output result of Canny Edge Detection can be the input image of the Hough Transform Circle,the result is as below.

[image]

Unfortunately, not all circles is detected and if i change the

`for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)`  into

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) // 24 is the no. of cans
```

I will get a Expression: vector subscript out of range. I am not sure why it is only able to detect 21 circles

Source code as below:-

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat src, src_gray;

int main()
{
Mat src1;

src1 = imread("cans.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
namedWindow("Original image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Original image", src1);


Mat gray, edge, draw;
cvtColor(src1, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Canny(gray, edge,50, 150, 3);
//50,150,3

edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);
namedWindow("Canny Edge", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Canny Edge", draw);
imwrite("output.jpg", draw);


waitKey(500);




/// Read the image
src = imread("output.jpg", 1);
Size size(932, 558);//the dst image size,e.g.100x100
resize(src, src, size);//resize image

/// Convert it to gray
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

/// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
GaussianBlur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

vector<Vec3f> circles;

/// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
HoughCircles(src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows / 8,200, 100, 0, 0);

/// Draw the circles detected
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    printf("are you um?\n");
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    // circle center
    circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
}

//  namedWindow("Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Hough Circle Transform Demo", src);
    line(src, Point(0, 288), Point(1024, 288), Scalar(225, 220, 225), 2, 8);
    // middle line
    line(src, Point(360, 0), Point(360, 576), Scalar(225, 220, 225), 2, 8);
    //break cans into 4 by 4
    line(src, Point(600, 0), Point(600, 576), Scalar(225, 220, 225), 2, 8);
                             //      x, y  
    imshow("Lines", src);
    imwrite("lineoutput.jpg", src);


    waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}
```

I had also manually typed out the coordinates for the lines to group them into 4 x 4.[image]
What should I change in order for it not to have any subscript out of range error and able to detect all circles?

Comment: you can not access more than what you have  found. It founds 21 circles, so the vector contains 21 circles. If you change the loop variable to 24, it will get subscript error cause the vector size is 21. You can not access more than its size. To get missing circles you can add the circles from your program. It will not always work but to some extent it will work. its like a grid of 6x4. From the centers distance you can easily assume which circles are missing.....

Comment: I don't think i'll manually add circles into it as I got 10+ images with different lighting and position.
Thanks! fixed the subscript error,my grid of 6x4 is probably just for show as it does nothing :l

Answer (score 2):

Okay solved my own question. Changed CV_BGR2GRAY to CV_RGB2GRAY,made the file ratio smaller, changing the circles min Radius and applying another threshold to get the circles.[image]

Comment: try different light and other conditions ... you will not have all the circles always. it might fail few :)

Comment: yes.. I tried with different lighting and unfortunately I couldn't get all the circle without changing the values of the codes :c
Is there any solution for that I wonder?

Comment: Feature matching such as Ransac and sift?